# Recursive function not calling

Tags: python, recursion, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Specifically I am trying to reduce the length for tensors for token classification.
I have a recursive function which will handle long texts, unfortunately the function splits the text only once and resulting in must match existing size error.

```py
def regex_extraction(texts):
   
    email_pattern = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+\s?@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,7}\b'
    url_pattern = r"(https?://www\.[^\s]+|https?://[^\s]+|[a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+[^\s]*|([a-zA-Z]{2,}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,})?/[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)[^\s]*|(https?://www\.[^\s]+|https?://[^\s]+))"
    phone_pattern = r'\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}'

    sanitized_texts = []
    email_matches = []
    url_matches = []
    phone_matches = []

    for index, text in enumerate(texts):
        text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
        text = re.sub(r'-{5,}', '', text)
        if index == 0:
            email_matches = re.findall(email_pattern, text)
            url_matches = re.findall(url_pattern, text)
            phone_matches = re.findall(phone_pattern, text)
        
        sanitized_text = re.sub(phone_pattern, '[PHONE]', re.sub(url_pattern, '[URL]', re.sub(email_pattern, '[EMAIL]', text)))
        sanitized_texts.append(sanitized_text)

    return sanitized_texts, email_matches, url_matches, phone_matches


def invoke_sagemaker_endpoint(text, recursion_depth=0):
    runtime = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')
    endpoint_name = "Inference Endpoint"  # Replace with your endpoint name
    
    try:
        response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,
                                           ContentType='application/json',
                                           Body=json.dumps({"inputs": text}))
        result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
        
    except Exception as e:
        error_message = str(e)
        if "must match the existing size" in error_message and recursion_depth <= 2: 
            logging.info('splitting text')
            delimiters = ['.', ',']
            split_point = len(text) // 2
            for delimiter in delimiters:
                position = text.rfind(delimiter, 0, split_point)
                if position != -1:
                    split_point = position + 1
                    break
            
            text_halves = [text[:split_point].strip(), text[split_point:].strip()]
            results = []

            recursion_depth += 1  # Increase recursion depth once for the entire loop

            for text_half in text_halves:
                response = invoke_sagemaker_endpoint(text_half, recursion_depth)
                anonymized_text = anonymize_page_text(text_half, response)
                results.append(anonymized_text)

            result = ''.join(results)
            
        else:
            logging.error(f"Error invoking SageMaker endpoint: {error_message}")
            raise e
    else:
        # If no exception, anonymize the result here
        result = anonymize_page_text(text, result)

    return result

def anonymize_page_text(page_text, sagemaker_response):
    """
    Anonymize entities in a given page text based on the provided SageMaker response.
    """
    new_text = ""
    previous_end = 0
    previous_entity = None

    for result in sagemaker_response:
        start, end = result['start'], result['end']
        entity_type = result['entity']

        # Add the text that's in between this entity and the previous one
        new_text += page_text[previous_end:start]

        # Replace the entity with its label, but skip single characters that are not adjacent to another entity
        if entity_type == 'I-PER' and previous_entity != 'I-PER':
            new_text += '[PERSON]'
        elif entity_type == 'I-LOC' and previous_entity != 'I-LOC':
            new_text += '[LOCATION]'
        elif entity_type not in ['I-PER', 'I-LOC']:
            new_text += page_text[start:end]  # If not an entity of interest, just append the original text

        previous_end = end
        previous_entity = entity_type

    # Add any remaining text after the last entity
    new_text += page_text[previous_end:]

    return new_text


if texts:
    sanitized_texts, email_matches, url_matches, phone_matches = regex_extraction(texts)
    logging.info(len(sanitized_texts[0]))
    logging.info(len(sanitized_texts[-1]))

    logging.info(sanitized_texts[0])
    logging.info(sanitized_texts[-1])
    
    if sanitized_texts:
        # Invoke the function with the first text item
        first_response = invoke_sagemaker_endpoint(sanitized_texts[0])
        logging.info(f"First Response: {first_response}")
        
        # If there is more than one text item, invoke the function with the last one
        if len(sanitized_texts) > 1:
            last_response = invoke_sagemaker_endpoint(sanitized_texts[-1])
            logging.info(f"Last Response: {last_response}")

        # Merge sanitized_texts into a single string
        final_text = ' '.join(sanitized_texts)
```

Texts is a list variable containing text chunks extracted from OCR:

```
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  ~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^ ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'   ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 535, in _api_call   ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 980, in _make_api_call  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary with message "{    ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  "code": 400,    ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  "type": "InternalServerException",  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  "message": "The expanded size of the tensor (735) must match the existing size (514) at non-singleton dimension 1. Target sizes: [1, 735]. Tensor sizes: [1, 514]"  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  }   ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  ". See https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=eu-west-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/huggingface-pytorch-inference-2023-09-26-10-13-06-479 in account 026588382219 for more information.  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  Traceback (most recent call last):  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  File "/app/main.py", line 313, in <module>  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  first_response = invoke_sagemaker_endpoint(sanitized_texts[0])  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  File "/app/main.py", line 118, in invoke_sagemaker_endpoint ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  anonymized_text = anonymize_page_text(text_half, response)  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  File "/app/main.py", line 141, in anonymize_page_text   ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  start, end = result['start'], result['end'] ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  Traceback (most recent call last):  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  object receivedBen_Mawdsley_CV.pdf  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  File "/app/main.py", line 94, in invoke_sagemaker_endpoint  ocr-embed
September 28, 2023 at 11:59 (UTC+2:00)  response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=endpoint_name,
```

I am expecting multiple recursion calls if the text is too long (to handle tensor error).

Comment: Hi. What question are you asking? Am I correct to understand that you have written some code, and that you expect your code to do something, but it does something else instead? What did you expect your code to do? And what is it doing instead?

Comment: Well excuse me i might have given too little context.
Texts contains a list of text chunks, which is passed to regex function to do some text preprocessing.
sanitized text is a returned list which calls for sagemaker endpoint for token classification. Function is imagined as a recursive function which handles too long text input. Current maximum token limit is 512, so if the error is caught "must match the existing size" it continues to split the text by some delimiter rules, but if the text is too long again, it should do recursive call BUT it doesn't.
It always splits it only once